# How to draw a line between two buttons in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have two buttons in my xml layout as shown bellow.

[image]

I used an activity for this button click. I want to draw a line between these buttons as shown. Could someone please help me to draw the line between this by using code or XML..

Comment: one way is you can use absolute layout and then put View (as line) where you want to put:)

Comment: Hi @xitij, I used absolute layout here. But How can I put View as diagonally(for diagonal line)?

Comment: I would recommend using a custom View and overriding onDraw() method for the complete view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an custom view to draw the line such as LineView and override the `onDraw`.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), m_paint);
}
```

Then use the XML to achieve the layout you want.

```
<com.android.drawable.LineView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightButton"
    android:layout_below="@id/leftButton"
    android:layout_above="@id/rightButton"
    />
```

Comment: Hi @dreamtale, thanks for your feed back... When I used this method. I got a line that fully covers My screen through buttons. I needs the line only between buttons. Can u help me for this..

Comment: @Binu Put the LineView and your two buttons in `RelativeLayout` then use the above XML so that let your LineView is bwtween the two buttons.