# Draw line through 2 view android

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, view, draw

I have two point as below:

> |- - - - Parent layout- - - -|
>   |- - - - Point A - - - - - - - -|
>   |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
>   |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
>   |- |- - - - - - - - - - -|- - - - -|
>   |- |- Child Layout-|- - - - -|
>   |- |- Point B- - - - -|- - - - -|
>   |- |- - - - - -- - - - - |- - - - -|
>   |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |

how i can draw line from point A to point B?

Thanks all support!

Comment: try way [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616223/android-draw-line-between-two-views) also see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258756/how-to-draw-a-line-between-two-buttons-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It simply
h
1.Just design one layout with width fillparent and height 2dp like that with background color and then merge into your main layout

2.one simple

```
<View android:width="fillparent"
android:height="2dp"
android:background="#000000/>
```

In this way you can add line to view

Answer (score 0):

use this code for `vertical` line. 
if u draw line from a to b just give a height in dp size

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_line1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_center="true" />
```

for `horizontal` line use this:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_line1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_center="true" />
```